# Communication between VMware through WiFi in bridged mode

Tags: networking, vmware, wireless-networking

I have a host with a WiFi connection working with some guests active under VMware. Each guest can communicate with the network through the host WiFi without problems but they cannot communicate between them.

Any ideas what might be happening or what can I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried putting the vm in nat mode   which will generally make the vm its own citizen on on the network istead of just bridging the connection from the network adapter